# Cranking start from time to time on a VW Golf mk4

Tags: electrical, starting, golf, air-intake, mk4

My VW Golf mk 4 has been cranking from time to time for the last 2 or 3 years, or perhaps a little bit more. It's not something that always happen and I believe that it's specially prone to do it when the weather is cold or specially humid. However, this winter —which has been specially bad with a lot of really dancing weather around zero— has been more prone to do it.

I've always thought that it is due to something related to the air intake, but lately I'm thinking that perhaps it's something on the electrical system.

I've been complaining about this to different mechanics —on the dealership and on another shops— and they never have been been able to tell me what is going on. I guess they look for some kind of signal on the VAG and since they aren't able to see anything, they just not pursuit anything. I guess in the VAG is not appearing anything since the car starts usually at first time.

On Nov, I had to change the starting engine because it totally died and I got a new one. So that is probably not it. Five years ago the starting coils were also changed, so those are probably fine too.

Another idea I have is the fuel pump, but when the car is up and running everything works fine.

What could be the usual suspects?

Comment: Does the car start on the second try, or does it need to sit for a while before it starts?  When it does eventually start, does it run normally?

Comment: No… usually there is no second time. It just starts, but it take more time than it should. If there is a second time —some times there is, but very rarely, at least for now— it always start and usually quite normal.

Comment: That's a tough one to diagnose remotely.  My first thought would be the fuel pump.  You could get someone to do a fuel pressure test, or do like I do and wait for it to get worse or fail. lol.